# Webpage jumps unusually after using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am using this code to hide and show my images under link tag. I put this html code in the middle of my site.

My problem is whenever I click on the link tag, my site jumps to the top from the middle. So viewers can't see the sliding effect and they have to scroll down again to come back to the middle.

How can I keep it from jumping to the top? I am using it in wordpress.

**HTML:**

```
<a class = "showul" href="#"> 24 hour front desk</a>
<img class = "hideul" src="http://localhost.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/recption-300x200.jpg" />

<a class="showul" href="#">Restaurant</a>
<img class="hideul" src="http://localhost.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/rest-300x200.jpg" alt="" />

<a class="showul" href="#"> Conference</a>
<img class="hideul" src="http://localhost.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/conference-300x200.jpg" alt="" />
```

**JavaScript:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".showul").click(function() {
        var $hideUl = $(this).siblings(".hideul");
        var show = !$hideUl.is(':visible');

        $('.hideul').slideUp('slow');
        if (show)
            $hideUl.slideToggle('slow');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace all the instances of `href="#"` with `href="javascript:void(0)"` that will fix issue

Comment: wow... this is awesome... It's working nicely ... Thank you very much.

Comment: @Spartacus void(0) is just the smallest script possible that evaluates as undefined. This is the best practice to stop the href action and fast way too.

Comment: No, it's absolutely not best practice. Best practice is to keep the HTML as light as possible and to avoid unnecessary repetition. In this case, you're adding javascript:void(0) to three separate elements, and if the case were larger, say 100 anchor tags, you're bloating your page. Whether it's 1 or 100 or 30000 anchor tags, best practice is to stop click propagation 1 time in the script, not inline with the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You need to stop the click propagation:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$(".showul").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $hideUl = $(this).siblings(".hideul");
    var show = !$hideUl.is(':visible');
    $('.hideul').slideUp('slow');
    if (show)
        $hideUl.slideToggle('slow');
});
});
```

Source: [preventDefault()](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

Answer (score 0):

Your click handler does not prevent the default action for clicking on the link.

An href of the form `#some-id` will jump the page to the point that the elemnt with that id is. If the id doesn't exist, or is omitted (just a `#`) then it will jump to the top of the page.

In jQuery, the easiest way to achieve this, is simply to return `false` from your click handler to prevent the default action from occurring.

```
$(".showul").click(function() {
    // ...
    return false;
});
```

The other way to do it is to call `preventDefault` on the event object

```
$(".showul").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The preferred option would be to add evt to the `click(function(evt) ...` and use `evt.preventDefault()` inside the click callback.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use preventDefault function to prevent the default action of href

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".showul").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $hideUl = $(this).siblings(".hideul");
        var show = !$hideUl.is(':visible');
        $('.hideul').slideUp('slow');
        if (show)
            $hideUl.slideToggle('slow');
    });
    });
```